# Как индексируются поисковиками сайты на базе MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Если сайт на базе MySQL и получается так, что есть только несколько универсальных страниц, а в них автоматом вставляются данные... как же тогда содержание базы может индексироваться поисковиками? Для этого нужно что-то сделать на php? 
Спасибо всем за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких проблем не будет и ничего дополнительного делать не нужно, разве что, не помешает карта сайта (sitemap). Огромное количество сайтов работают на PHP+MySQL и прекрасно индексируются всеми поисковиками.

Comment: Спасибо! Все понятно)

Answer (score 1):

Будет проиндексирован!

Открою секрет, сейчас все сайты с динамическим контентом. И каждая страница такого сайта индексируется поисковиками.

Comment: Хорошие новости! Спасибо!